# How to pass request to symfony controller with parameters using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, annotations, symfony-forms

I am using DataTables, but that doesn't impact my problem.
My twig template has form

```html
{{ form_start(form_filter, {'attr': 
          {'role': 'form','onsubmit':'callFilterData();return false;'}}) }}
                    {{ form_widget() }}
                    {{ form_end(form_filter) }}
         <table id="a"></table>
```

I am preventing page to reload and making ajax call. 
My javaScript looks:

```js
function callFilterData(){
    $('a').DataTable({
        ajax: Routing.generate('ajax_admin', {selectedDate: date}),
        paging: false,
        data:date,
        columns: [
            {data: 'factor', "defaultContent": "--"}
        ]
    });
}
```

My controller looks:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/table",
 * name="ajax_admin",
 *     options={"expose"=true})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
 */
public function ajaxMakeTable(Request $request)
{ 
    $form = $this->createForm(DatePickerType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $month = $form->get('selectedDate')->getData();
    }
    return ['factor'=>$month];
}
```

I have no idea why my ajax call doesn't execute and table isn't rendered as expected. Where to look for clues?

Comment: `$('a').DataTable()` => `$('#a')` or it's a copy/paste error ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the form part of Profiler? You can also use $form->getErrors(true, false); to see errors programmatically

Comment: @G1.3, it is a typo, testing this case.

Comment: if, in your case, `$form->get('selectedDate')` resolves to `null` - that is rather expected. Have you tried dumping `$request->query->get('selectedDate')`? Before firing up the `AJAX` call, open your developer tool and find what your browser sends to your server...